# Thermistors' colour coding same as the resistors'?

Tags: resistors, thermistor, colour-coding

***WARNING:*** 30V was a mistake -- better to keep voltage down 12V as a beginner! I tested it over a very short time. Got the things hot over a long time with much less voltage -- apparently not enough energy was dissipated to destroy the components.

Thermistors are a type of resistors, according to Wikipedia. Two thermistors black-white (18p written on it) and gold-orange-gold-yellow (no text). If the colour coding is the same to [resistors](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/2869/resistors-with-ends-of-the-same-colour) and reading up-to-bottom, the former is 8 Ohms and the last one is 4k Ohms. I tested both with 30V: the former warm, the last not warm, the current 0,0A (not measurable with my equipment).

**Sizes** are 0.2cm times 0.3cm for both of the components.

**Accepted Power Estimate by size[(tip)](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/2864/at-what-current-and-voltage-typical-resistors-explode/2865#2865):** `3.14*(0.025m)^2 = 0.00196... so P ~=10^-3`

- How to estimate current as it was below `10^-2`?
- How to read thermistors' colour coding and what does 18p mean, 18 pico Ohms or some change?

Comment: 30V is too much for a thermistor unless the thermistor resistance is very large > 10k Ohms. If the thermistor resistance is very large you will still experience a significant amount of self-heating with the thermistor. Instead of applying a fixed voltage and measuring current have you just tried measuring resistance directly at a known temperature?

Answer (score 1):

Thermistors are only a type of resistor in a limited sense.  Within a given temp. range they behave linearly in current.  The packaging of Thermistors varies quite a lot, Glass beads to plastic packs.  As far as I know there is no color coding that is common.  I did a check on Omega and Honeywell's site.  No mention of a color coding there either.  I would think the 18p is a manufacturing code and not an electrical spec.

Also, testing with 30V!!  How big are these things!

Comment: If they really were 4 ohms, that would give a current of 30/4 amps and therefore power of 225 watts which instantly destroy most components.

Comment: I wasn't worried about you... just the component.  Not to sound unconcerned!